# How to extract date from a timestamp who data type is int

Tags: mysql

The existing database's table has a column "dateline" with int data type.  It stores timestamp.  How can I extract date from it.

```
Dateline (int)
_____________
1314182844
1298122381
1298122956
```

Advise on how can I extract the date part from this in the following query.

```
select * from TableName where Dateline between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-31'
```

I tried using cast, dateformat, convert, but nothing gave the desired result.

P.S.  PLEASE NOTE THE DATA TYPE STORAGE IS INTEGER..

Comment: This may give you a clue: [epoch time and MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825739/epoch-time-and-mysql-query)

Comment: Look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql/6267625#6267625

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME(Dateline)`.

See more information [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php).

As atomman mentions in the comments, you should use `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(Dateline))` if you only want the date part.

Comment: Would it be `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampcolumn))`, since he is only cares about the date.

Comment: Well, the datatype is int and the above code does not work...The only value I get is 1970-01-01 for whatever timestamp it is

Comment: It is working for other tables with same int data type.  Im not sure why it is giving garbage value only for this table :(

Comment: Got it..Thanks..Few of the initial values of the database are garbage values.  sorry for the confusion.  thanks again for all inputs

Comment: @user1808995 Glad to have been of assistance :)