# How to retrieve records with muliple timezones

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I'm creating a site where i need to use registered users timezones to determine if they are available to receive emails on specific days based on what they set in their dashboard.

The main thing im wanting to tackle is that i would like the option of showing those users who are available NOW at the top of the results to save people having to search through pages of people to find those who are available.

I have a rough idea of a function i could use to show/hide the email form on the users page... Its more about the query on the search page that will display all the users and how best to order the results.

The default timezone will be GMT.

So if today was monday and the following users had their availability set as:

```
USER | timezone | availability_today | emails_received

1 | America/Los_Angeles | 2 | 1 (still available)

2 | America/New_York | 0 | 0 (not available)

3 | Europe/London | 1 | 1 (not available)
```

I think its more a question of what date/timezone I'm actually saving/accessing. In the email table id have a DATE_SENT column so i can count how many emails have been sent to compare against their availability. But if the site is GMT... that wouldn't be the users correct time if they were in the US or Australia...

Like i said, its more about the select statement on the search page that i cant figure out with all the timezones there would be. My host doesn't support CONVERT_TZ.

Or do i just calculate it all in GMT?

I'm just as confused asking the question as you are reading it im sure. Hopefully someone understands enough to offer a suggestion. Its probably not as confusing as im making it out to be.

EDIT:-

The issue:

Say its Monday GMT. In a users (not visitors) country its tuesday and they have their availability set as 0. If i use GMT its monday on the server so an email will get through. And on Tuesday (Weds in the users country) they wont get one.

Visitors wont have to register to view the search results. They will need to if they want to email a user. The users page is easy enough as its dealing with one conversion.

Comment: Store everything in GMT.  Convert to the local time zone when displaying to users or reading their input.

Comment: Why do people make comments instead of answers?  Gordon Linoff is 100% correct and he deserves his 25 points.  Don't waste your time dealing with data in mixed time zones; that way leads madness.

Comment: I intent on saving it in GMT. Its more about the display of results based on the different timezones and what the user sets their availability as i cant wrap my head around (see edit)

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on how a single integer is supposed to determine availability.  Is this a time of day? Or is it a count of items of some kind?  If not a time of day, how are you determining the range of availability?   Here's an idea that will clarify - work through your problem set without time zones first.  Just assume everyone's time zone is the same.  Then when you can show how *that* is working, you can ask about how to adjust it to support multiple time zones.  Although the solution will probably be obvious to you at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options...

(1) Store everything in GMT in datetime column. You can perform the manipulation on your end by performing MySQL queries such as

```
SELECT 'my date' - INTERVAL 5 HOUR
```

(2) Store everything in timestamp columns in the user's current timezone. You can set the timezone for the current database connection by executing the query...

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'
```

View the current time zone with

```
SELECT @@time_zone;
```

Replace `'Europe/London'` with the correct timezone. When MySQL uses timestamps it internally stores the data in GMT. When you pull the data back out, MySQL will automatically convert the time back into whatever timezone the client has currently set.

Answer (score 0):

Store times in epoch time, [converting for display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825739/epoch-time-and-mysql-query) only using [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). Forget multiple timezones, as Mr Sokolov so eloquently put it,

> that way leads madness

Comment: Hey. I'm not wanting 20 different timezones in the DB. That's not what i was asking. Its mainly trying to figure out how to tackle the differences in timezones to show those with availability at the top of the results taking into consideration the timezone differences.

Comment: Have a column for the timezone and the epoch time, mate. That's the only way I can think of to do it that's not maddening.